# Newtonsoft Json.NET ReferenceLoopHandling and JavascriptDateTimeConverter

Tags: c#, datetime, json.net

I need Json.NET to serialize using both JavaScriptDateTimeConverter and ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore. None of the signatures on JsonConvert.SerializeObject allow setting both of these setting, as far as I can tell.

I can do:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.Data, new JavaScriptDateTimeConverter());
```

Or I can do:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.Data, new JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize
            });
```

But I can't do both. The signatures I get for SerializeObject are as follows. The 6th and 5th ones allow me to do the above respectively.

[image: SerializeObject signatures]

I've looked into setting these settings globally but I haven't had much luck.

Anyone know of a way to serialize using both of these settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You specify your `JavaScriptDateTimeConverter` inside the `JsonSerializerSettings`' with the `Converters` property:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.Data, new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    Converters = new List<JsonConverter> { new JavaScriptDateTimeConverter() },
    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize
});
```

Actually the overload which takes the `JsonConverter` array internally creates a `JsonSerializerSettings` and sets its Converters property.

Comment: Bit confusing to have it in both places. Thanks for the answer!